# Sorting accented names that start either with lowercase or uppercase

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am looking to sort the following list which contains names written in different ways:

```
l=['André','Gerald','Nicole','François','Fraçois','andré']
```

The expected result is:

```
['André', 'andré', 'Fraçois', 'François' 'Gerald', 'Nicole']
```

However, I am could not obtain it. Until now, I have tried to do a double sorting with the sorted command:

```
l=sorted(sorted(l, key=str.casefold), key=unidecode.unidecode)
```

But my result is not quite what I am looking for:

```
['André', 'Fraçois', 'François', 'Gerald', 'Nicole', 'andré']
```

Do you guys know any other command that could bring me the correct sorting?

Comment: @S3DEV `Fraçois` should be before `François`

Comment: @Sujay - Yep, just spotted that, thanks.  I was strictly focusing on case, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```py
import unidecode
l = ['André','Gerald','Nicole','François','Fraçois','andré']

l = sorted(l, key=lambda s: unidecode.unidecode(s).lower())
```

Result:

```py
['André', 'andré', 'Fraçois', 'François', 'Gerald', 'Nicole']
```

Python sort is [stable](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts), therefore a nested sort would actually work.

Comment: Are you sure that dumbing down to ascii is the desired behavior?

Comment: Good morning! Thank you for the answer!
But one more thing:  why did you insert the 's' character exclusively in unidecode.unidecode? 
Wasn't the code suposed to be: 
key=lambda s: unidecode.unidecode(s).lower(s)?

Comment: strings in python are objects - as such, they offer methods. The call of unicode.unidecode(s) returns a string object, so by using lower() we are actually calling the lower method of the returned string-object - think 'string.lower()'. The method call to 'lower()' takes no arguments - it returns a new string-object that is a duplicate of the one calling it, except that all characters are now lowercase. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower

Answer (score 1):

You could use normalize from unicodedata to remove de diacritic marks:

```
import unicodedata

l=['André','Gerald','Nicole','François','Fraçois','andré']

sl = sorted(l,key=lambda n:unicodedata.normalize("NFD",n).lower())

print(sl)
# ['André', 'andré', 'Fraçois', 'François', 'Gerald', 'Nicole']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is case sensitivity, then flatten the case (only) for sorting:

```
>>> sorted(l, key= lambda x : x.lower())
['André', 'andré', 'François', 'Fraçois', 'Gerald', 'Nicole']
```

If you do not like the case-insensitive Unicode ordering that this produces, i.e. if you really want to throw unidecode into the mix, fold it together into the sort key function... that's @JLam's answer, so I won't steal their thunder.